# Удаление элемента в массиве обьектов. Телеграмм бот

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

Всем привет! Я пишу своего телеграмм бота и у меня встал вопрос. Как я смог бы удалить элемент из массива?
К примеру:

Учет финансовых расходов: Добавление расходов, удаление. Я вношу  свои траты, они сохраняются в массиве. Допустим я ввел неправильно и захотел удалить расход, так? Как мне это реализовать?

Использовал метод  *splice*,удалялись все элементы. Я же хочу чтобы когда пользователь вводит команду "удалить расход" ,то значение которое он хочет удалить, удалялось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов много предложу такие

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

let selectedIndex = 2;

arr.splice(selectedIndex, 1);

console.log(arr);

let selectedItem = 6;

let result = arr.reduce((acc, item)=>{ if (item != selectedItem) acc.push(item); return acc;}, []);

console.log(result);

selectedItem = 5;

result = arr.filter(item=>item != selectedItem);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленное решение) все работает.